# Contributing Quick fix in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-jdt

Is it possible to contribute quick fix in eclipse for non-java code (say xtend scripts or ant scripts ).

If yes, which extension should I use ?

Thanks,
Santhosh

Answer (score 1):

IMHO no. You have to create a plug-in and write code in Java, If you have to extend/contribute to eclipse functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.Thanks for your suggestions !!

I  used the extension point **org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution** as suggested.

The below link gives a detailed explanation

http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/eclipse/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.tests/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/tests/quickfix/MarkerResolutionGenerator.java.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You can contribute quick fixes for anything as long as you know the marker type of the problem marker that you want to fix. Use the extension point:

```
org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution
```

In there you specify the marker type (for example `org.eclipse.ant.ui.buildFileProblem` for ant build file markers) and a custom class to generate quick fix resolutions (`IMarkerResolution` instances). You can browse for the marker types if you're not sure of the right one.